# Custom date format cannot be parsed. (Java)

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, formatting

I have to use a custom date format in Java. It contains microseconds although Java doesn't provide support for microseconds. Because of that I filled the time pattern with zeroes, which work fine when formatting, but I cannot parse date-strings with that pattern.

Is there a simple workaround or must I handle microseconds on my own (with String functions)?

```
@Test
public void testDateFormat() throws ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSS000");
    String theDate = format.format(new Date());
    // this will fail:
    format.parse(theDate);
}
```

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2010-01-25-12.40.35.769000"

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that the pattern used in SimpleDateFormat unfortunately have different meanings depending on whether it is used as a parser or as a formatter. As a formatter, your pattern does what is expected, the output will end with the millisecond value formatted as three digits followed by three 0 characters, e.g:

2010-01-25-14.17.47.307000

Used as a parser, the "SSS" pattern will however match an arbitrary number of digits and parse the above example as 307000 ms. After having parsed the ms field, the parser will still look for a "000" substring and fail with an exception, since you've reached the end of the input string, without fulfilling the requirements of the pattern.

Since there is no pattern for a µs value in SimpleDateFormat, you will have to write your own wrapper to strip the input string for the last three 0 characters, before feeding it to SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to jarnbjo's answer, if you need the microseconds, you might be able to use java.sql.Timestamp:

```
Date dateToMillis = format.parse(theDate.substring(0, 23));
DateFormat timestampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(timestampFormat.format(dateToMillis) + theDate.substring(23,26));
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2010-01-25-12.40.35.769000" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS" ) 
)
```

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

These old classes were limited to tracking [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), three digits of decimal fraction. The modern java.time classes resolve to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), for *nine* digits of decimal fraction.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2010-01-25-12.40.35.769000" );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2010-01-25T12:40:35.769

## ISO 8601

Tip: Rather than invent your own format to textually represent a date-time value, stick to the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

The java.time classes use the standard formats by default. You can see that format in the output above. The `T` separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

Add a `''` around the zeros, like so: `"yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSS'000'"`

> Date and time formats are specified by
>   date and time pattern strings. Within
>   date and time pattern strings,
>   unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z' and
>   from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as
>   pattern letters representing the
>   components of a date or time string.
>   Text can be quoted using single quotes
>   (') to avoid interpretation. "''"
>   represents a single quote. All other
>   characters are not interpreted;
>   they're simply copied into the output
>   string during formatting or matched
>   against the input string during
>   parsing.

Comment: My testcase with single quotes still throws a ParseException.

Comment: Because '000' are not "letters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z'".