# SimpleDateFormat parse returns bad date

Tags: java, date

I am using SimpleDateFormat in order to parse a String. Here is an example:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat longStringFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
[some code here]
Date dirDate = longStringFormat.parse("2014-04-03T06:00:00.376542900Z");
```

When I check dirDate in debug mode, or print it, the date I get is `Mon Apr 07 14:35:42 FET 2014`.

Why do I get such an offset? It cannot be counted as a timezone offset(although it seems already wrong to apply an offset). How can I obtain a Date object depicting the exact same time as the String?

Comment: Please don't assume Java is wrong.

Comment: The SSS represents a millisecond value, not a fraction of seconds.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis =)) I do not assume THEY are wrong, I assume that I haven't understood it properly. Maybe that is the error. What format string would you suggest for my case?

Comment: Here's a workaround if you need the microseconds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2132605/2591612

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you're specifying this value for the number of milliseconds: 376542900. That's 104 hours, 35 minutes, 42 seconds and 900 milliseconds... hence the issue.

Unfortunately, it looks like `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't have a way of understanding that you're giving it "fractions of a second" instead of "a number of milliseconds". I strongly suspect (although I haven't tried it) that Java 8 would work properly (possibly with a longer pattern) and that Joda Time may also handle it - are either of those an option? Otherwise, you'll need to use string manipulation to get the string into a more manageable form.

(As an aside, you should also set the `SimpleDateFormat`'s time zone to UTC, as that's what's being specified in the text.)

Comment: None of them is an option. Other suggestions except .substring() or .split()?

Comment: @Dragos: I'd use `substring` to get rid of the extra digits, basically.

Comment: More accurately, SimpleDateFormat can't handle microseconds. If you reduce it down to 3 decimal places it is fine (though it would lead to a less accurate time value maybe)

Comment: You can use `Timestamp` like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2132605/2591612

Comment: @staticx: It's not just microseconds in this case - it's nanoseconds. I assumed that Dragos just wanted to parse the value and get a reduced-accuracy `Date`.

Comment: True, I was not accurate in my statement. That being said, you can truncate all but the last three using `substring` and get the date needed.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2014-04-03T06:00:00.376542900Z");
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-04-03T06:00:00.376542900Z
```

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>