# java date format with 6 digit micro/milli second

Tags: java, date, format

From the Postgres Database I am getting a 6 digit microsecond (its actually a ) e.g. 2014-11-10 04:05:06.**999999**

now when i apply a date format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" it converts the 999999 to corresponding seconds/minutes resulting in incorrect date. See code snippet below

```
String dt = "2014-11-10 04:05:06.999999";           
        String timeseriesFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";            
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(timeseriesFormat);
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(dt);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

results in 2014-11-10 **04:21:45.999**

I want to rather truncate the last 3 digits and keep a date of **2014-11-10 04:05:06.999**.
How to truncate it? I do not want to use any framework like joda etc.

Comment: Are the microseconds coming out 0-padded?  `2014-11-10 04:05:06.15` vs. `2014-11-10 04:05:06.000015` makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

## *java.time*

Use *java.time* classes, built into Java 8 and later. Never use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `GregorianCalendar`, and `Timestamp`.

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```java
String input = "2014-11-10 04:05:06.999999".replace( " " , "T" ) ; // Convert from SQL style to ISO 8601 standard format where `T` separates the year-month-day portion from hour-minute-second portion.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

### Not a moment

Be aware that a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Your input lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we do not know if your mean 4 AM on the 10th in Tokyo Japan, 4 AM in Toulouse France, or 4 AM in Toledo Ohio US — three very different moments, several hours apart on the timeline.

So you would be storing the `LocalDateTime` object’s value in a Postgres database column of type [`TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

### A moment

If your intent was to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, you most know for certain the intended time zone.

Let's say you know the 4 AM was meant to be in Tokyo Japan time zone. Apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to the `LocalDateTime` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Unfortunately, the JDBC 4.2 spec does not require support for the two most commonly used types, [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). No matter, we can easily convert to [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), for which support is required by JDBC spec.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Such a value, a specific point on the timeline, should be written to a database column of type [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Write to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## `java.sql.Timestamp`

If you cannot move to Java 8, then you should be using your JDBC driver to get a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object. That class is a hack, but it works. It is a java.util.Date but tracks the fractional seconds to resolution of nanoseconds instead of milliseconds. So it will preserve the microseconds used by Postgres.

You can use it as a java.util.Date but in other contexts you'll lose your extra resolution.

But are you really stuck with Java 6, 7, or earlier in the year 2020 now? Best to move to either Java 8 or Java 11, the two [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) versions.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate to this one [Custom date format cannot be parsed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132247/custom-date-format-cannot-be-parsed-java)

Conclusion is `SimpleDateFormat` does not support microsecond, and you'll need your own parser

Try this:

```
System.out.println(
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.").format(microseconds/1000)
+String.format("%06d", microseconds%1000000));
```

Comment: Ok...does anyone have a custom parser to share?

Comment: Java 8 and later **now has such a parser built-in**, in the java.time framework. See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26905439/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Try `dt.substring(0, dt.length() - 3)`

Comment: that is just an example. however from database I get a Date object not String. if I convert to String the above problem is already seen hence its too late to apply your fix.

Comment: @user1712512 This comment contradicts your Question which says you have a String.